# NAS to store Firebird database

Tags: firebird

I read this blog saying that it is not recommended to use NAS as a firebird data media. Is there an experience that you use NAS as firebird data storage?

I plan to buy NAS synology to store the firebird database.

http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.FirebirdPerformanceRecommendations

Comment: It would be better then to run the Firebird on the NAS too.
To avoid for example data corruption on network brownout.

Comment: This means that the firebird machine is installed on the NAS, not the SMB data sharing.

Comment: I don't think this is suitable for Stack Overflow, as it is not a programming question, and ask for recommendations/opinions. I suggest you ask on the firebird-support mailing list instead.

Answer (score 1):

NAS in fact is a file server that uses network protocols for data exchange.

Firebird uses intensive small block reads/writes file operations at different offsets.

Some network protocols like FTP, FTPS, SFTP works at file level, meaning they are incompatible with Firebird.

Other network protocols like SMB, NFS supports file block level operations. But their problem is low latency, which will result in poor performance, due to multiple layers and long chain of involved components compared to a local/direct storage and low guarantee that your database keep its logical integrity and atomicity due to network communication, multiple caches and power failures.

Recent protocol versions SMBv3, NFSv4 have added many improvements and optimizations working with small blocks, decreased latency, RDMA support and accordingly network cards that support it, using 10Gbps+ bandwidth, ethernet/or fiber channel. Devices with persistent cache or even not NAS but SAN solutions. But they cost a lot and are used now mainly at Enterprise level.

Concluding, better to keep databases near to your Firebird server, using direct file access.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187347/discussion-on-answer-by-marcodor-nas-to-store-firebird-database).